# TFS 2017 - Cannot Modify Current Iteration Board

Tags: tfs

We are using TFS Version 15.105.25910.0 and I have created a custom state - Blocked.

In the current Sprint View, when we change a task to this state, it disappears from the board as there is no column to support blocked (makes sense).

However if I click on User Stories, I can create a blocked column and move my user stories into blocked, but cannot do this with tasks.

Is there a reason why the current iteration view does not allow the creation of a custom column and/or how do I create a view similar to User Stories for Tasks only.

Comment: Hi GT, did you get a chance to implement the solution that I suggested? Were you able to resolve? If my reply helped and your issue solved. Appreciate for marking it as an answer, which will also helps others in the community.

Comment: Yes worked perfectly thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your description, seems you just want to add   Blocked-state column in below page:

[image]

Use these Steps:

1. Export work item (e.g. task) through WitAdmin command.
2. Add custom state to workflow section
3. Export ProcessConfiguration process file through WitAdmin command.
4. Add state item in TaskBacklog=>States section. For example:

   `<States>
     <State type="Proposed" value="To Do" />
     <State type="InProgress" value="In Progress" />
     <State type="InProgress" value="Blocked" />
     <State type="Complete" value="Done" />
   </States>`
5. Import modified work item file and process file to the team project
6. Check the result in web access.

As for more details how to use WitAdmin command to export and import process configure file. Please refer our official tutorial here--[Import and export process configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/witadmin/witadmin-import-export-process-configuration?view=tfs-2018&viewFallbackFrom=vsts&redirectedfrom=MSDN) .The exported xml file could be edited through NotePad.

Answer (score 0):

You need t modify the team project process config file and add there the new state ("Blocked").

1. Export the file with `witadmin exportprocessconfig /collection:YOU_COLLECTION_URL /p:YOUR_TEAM_PROJECT /f:c:\processconfig.xml`
2. Open the file (`c:\processconfig.xml`) and search the `<TaskBacklog category="Microsoft.TaskCatgerory" ... >` node.
3. In the above node you have `States` node, add there the new state:

   ```
   <States>
      <State type="Proposed" value="Active" />
      <State type="Proposed" value="Blocked" />
      <State type="InProgress" value="In Progress" />
      <State type="Complete" value="Done" />
   </States>
   ```
4. Import the file with `witadmin importprocessconfig /collection:YOUR_COLLECTION_URL /p:YOUR_TEAM_PROJECT /f:c:\processconfig.xml`

Now you will see in the iteration board also the Blocked state :)